# First order differential equation, getting from one step to another

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

I don't understand how to get the last equation, the first three are no problem,  I just can't get the last equation from the third one.

Comment: I tried breaking out $dy/dx$ but I still get $2/x$

Comment: it's the last line in my post, but not the problem (Oh, C is added when you integrate and I haven't integrated yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is written wrong. They meant to write

$\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{y}{x})=e^x$

and it is clear this is implies $\frac{y'}{x}-\frac{y}{x^2}=e^x$.

Im not exactly sure what the purpose of the third line is.

Note: if you don't believe me, plug the top and bottom equations into wolfram alpha and you will get different solutions.

Comment: I was more concerned with the steps, I checked our slides and the teacher gets exactly the same thing, it's just that I didn't understand how, and now that I checked in wolfram (ipad) the steps are the same

Comment: not sure what to say. according to wolfram, the first equation implies $y=cx+xe^x$ and the other implies $y=\pm\sqrt{2}\sqrt{c+e^x(x+1)}$

Comment: someone posted that I should use reverse product rule, although can't find the post now, anyways, it works. i.e. $g'f+f'g=(fg)'$ don't know why the teacher didn't go through this or even mention it.

Comment: thats what i mean by "it is clear this implies". but still only of the teacher meant to write d/dx not dy/dx

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that you wrote it without the y, thought it weird that you wrote the same thing again but now I see what you meant XD. Thank you!

Comment: should have mentioned. it makes a big difference since d\dx operates on the stuff inside the parenthesis but dy/dx would just be multiplied by said stuff